# Word Links Update Manually but not Automatically

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, links

We are using Microsoft Word 2003 documents for contracts.  We are trying to link to a 2003 Excel file for the dynamic and redundant information listed in the contract like customer information, job information, etc.  We insert the links via edit>paste special>as a RTF type and as a Link.  The links are set to update automatically and Word is set to update links upon open.  Word even asks to update links on open, which we say yes to, but the links do not get updated also, going into the links dialog via the edit menu and selecting all the links then clicking update does nothing either.

But, right clicking a link and selecting "update link" will open the referenced excel file which brings up an excel dialog we have to answer, and then it closes excel with the link being updated.

***Why will the links update manually but not automatically?***

Any ideas?